# How to get contact picture on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to get a contact picture or contact image on Windows phone 
i am using following code but not able to get contact picture, i want to save user contact picture into sqlite database

```
foreach (var result in e.Results)
        {

            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(result.GetPicture());
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = bmp;

        }
```

Comment: Did u try implementing the converter , i think the above code same as in msdn snippet. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh286418(v=vs.105).aspx 
Please see the `ContactPictureConverter `

Comment: Don't forget to add Capability `ID_CAP_CONTACTS`

Comment: Eldho i want the contact picture url string that i can save my database and in a ContactPictureConverter method you can display the picture that i have already done but still i didnt get pic url

Comment: `GetPicture()` is returning a `stream` you cannot save that as string

Comment: If you save in your database there may be chances to change the original data in the Contact

`Contact data` is provided as a read-only snapshot. If your app needs fresh data, repeat the original search periodically.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj207071(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Eldho i know that is there any solution for this problem